# How to override *only* left click on anchor?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, dom-events, mouseevent

I know I can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop a link from being followed.  But I only want to prevent the default action on a plain left-click or touch-tap.  shift-left-click, ctrl-left-click, right click, and middle click should all perform the default action.

How can I detect a plain left-click or touch tap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) properties like [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button), [altKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/altKey), [shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey) & [ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey) to do this

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  snippet.log('button: ' + event.button);
  snippet.log('ctrlKey: ' + event.ctrlKey);
  snippet.log('shiftKey : ' + event.shiftKey);
  snippet.log('altKey : ' + event.altKey);

  if (event.button == 0 && !event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey && !event.altKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<a id="test" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">test</a>
```

Comment: i added `metaKey` as well.  thanks.  i was hoping these would be a single property for key like `button`.